Is there any way to change property names (to remove the x5f that replaces underscores) in dynamic apex classes generated from External Services?
When using External Services to generate Dynamic Apex classes for use in no-code solutions like Flows, if a property has an underscore in it, the underscore is replaced with "x5f" in the class's property names.
Thankfully, with the external API I'm using, everything works fine; it just makes using Flow Actions a little less readable.
API definition file for External Services:

Dynamic Apex Class:

Display in Flow builder:

